# php artisan test: ERROR Command "test" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to run my unit tests using the built in laravel commands.

I am getting the following error when running `php artisan test`.

`ERROR Command "test" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?`

Not sure why the command is not available.

When I run `php artisan` I get the following available commands.

```
Laravel Framework 10.3.0

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about                                                       Display basic information about your application
  clear-compiled                                              Remove the compiled class file
  completion                                                  Dump the shell completion script
  db                                                          Start a new database CLI session
  docs                                                        Access the Laravel documentation
  down                                                        Put the application into maintenance / demo mode
  env                                                         Display the current framework environment
  help                                                        Display help for a command
  inspire                                                     Display an inspiring quote
  list                                                        List commands
  migrate                                                     Run the database migrations
  optimize                                                    Cache the framework bootstrap files
  serve                                                       Serve the application on the PHP development server
  tinker                                                      Interact with your application
  ui                                                          Swap the front-end scaffolding for the application
  up                                                          Bring the application out of maintenance mode
 auth
  auth:clear-resets                                           Flush expired password reset tokens
 cache
  cache:clear                                                 Flush the application cache
  cache:forget                                                Remove an item from the cache
  cache:prune-stale-tags                                      Prune stale cache tags from the cache (Redis only)
  cache:table                                                 Create a migration for the cache database table
 channel
  channel:list                                                List all registered private broadcast channels
 check
  check:gd_stats_dashboard_data                               Check gd_stats_dashboard_data
  check:users_dashboard_clients                               Check users at dashboard clients
 clear
  clear:cache_data                                            Clear cache data.
 config
  config:cache                                                Create a cache file for faster configuration loading
  config:clear                                                Remove the configuration cache file
 db
  db:monitor                                                  Monitor the number of connections on the specified database
  db:seed                                                     Seed the database with records
  db:show                                                     Display information about the given database
  db:table                                                    Display information about the given database table
  db:wipe                                                     Drop all tables, views, and types
 debugbar
  debugbar:clear                                              Clear the Debugbar Storage
 elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:create-service-index                          ElasticSearch - Create services index
 env
  env:decrypt                                                 Decrypt an environment file
  env:encrypt                                                 Encrypt an environment file
 event
  event:cache                                                 Discover and cache the application's events and listeners
  event:clear                                                 Clear all cached events and listeners
  event:generate                                              Generate the missing events and listeners based on registration
  event:list                                                  List the application's events and listeners
 financials
  financials:export                                           Financials Export to nova
 key
  key:generate                                                Set the application key
 lang
  lang:publish                                                Publish all language files that are available for customization
 laravel-elasticsearch
  laravel-elasticsearch:utils:alias-create                    
  laravel-elasticsearch:utils:alias-remove-index              
  laravel-elasticsearch:utils:alias-switch-index              
  laravel-elasticsearch:utils:index-create                    
  laravel-elasticsearch:utils:index-create-or-update-mapping  
  laravel-elasticsearch:utils:index-delete                    
  laravel-elasticsearch:utils:index-exists                    
 livewire
  livewire:configure-s3-upload-cleanup                        Configure temporary file upload s3 directory to automatically cleanup files older than 24hrs
  livewire:copy                                               Copy a Livewire component
  livewire:delete                                             Delete a Livewire component
  livewire:discover                                           Regenerate Livewire component auto-discovery manifest
  livewire:make                                               Create a new Livewire component
  livewire:move                                               Move a Livewire component
  livewire:publish                                            Publish Livewire configuration
  livewire:stubs                                              Publish Livewire stubs
 make
  make:cast                                                   Create a new custom Eloquent cast class
  make:channel                                                Create a new channel class
  make:command                                                Create a new Artisan command
  make:component                                              Create a new view component class
  make:controller                                             Create a new controller class
  make:event                                                  Create a new event class
  make:exception                                              Create a new custom exception class
  make:export                                                 Create a new export class
  make:factory                                                Create a new model factory
  make:import                                                 Create a new import class
  make:job                                                    Create a new job class
  make:listener                                               Create a new event listener class
  make:livewire                                               Create a new Livewire component
  make:mail                                                   Create a new email class
  make:middleware                                             Create a new middleware class
  make:migration                                              Create a new migration file
  make:model                                                  Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:notification                                           Create a new notification class
  make:observer                                               Create a new observer class
  make:policy                                                 Create a new policy class
  make:provider                                               Create a new service provider class
  make:request                                                Create a new form request class
  make:resource                                               Create a new resource
  make:rule                                                   Create a new validation rule
  make:scope                                                  Create a new scope class
  make:seeder                                                 Create a new seeder class
  make:test                                                   Create a new test class
 migrate
  migrate:fresh                                               Drop all tables and re-run all migrations
  migrate:install                                             Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh                                             Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset                                               Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback                                            Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status                                              Show the status of each migration
 model
  model:prune                                                 Prune models that are no longer needed
  model:show                                                  Show information about an Eloquent model
 notifications
  notifications:table                                         Create a migration for the notifications table
 optimize
  optimize:clear                                              Remove the cached bootstrap files
 package
  package:discover                                            Rebuild the cached package manifest
 queue
  queue:batches-table                                         Create a migration for the batches database table
  queue:clear                                                 Delete all of the jobs from the specified queue
  queue:failed                                                List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:failed-table                                          Create a migration for the failed queue jobs database table
  queue:flush                                                 Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget                                                Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen                                                Listen to a given queue
  queue:monitor                                               Monitor the size of the specified queues
  queue:prune-batches                                         Prune stale entries from the batches database
  queue:prune-failed                                          Prune stale entries from the failed jobs table
  queue:restart                                               Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry                                                 Retry a failed queue job
  queue:retry-batch                                           Retry the failed jobs for a batch
  queue:table                                                 Create a migration for the queue jobs database table
  queue:work                                                  Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon
 route
  route:cache                                                 Create a route cache file for faster route registration
  route:clear                                                 Remove the route cache file
  route:list                                                  List all registered routes
 schedule
  schedule:clear-cache                                        Delete the cached mutex files created by scheduler
  schedule:list                                               List all scheduled tasks
  schedule:run                                                Run the scheduled commands
  schedule:test                                               Run a scheduled command
  schedule:work                                               Start the schedule worker
 schema
  schema:dump                                                 Dump the given database schema
 send
  send:invoice_next_email                                     Send invoice next email.
  send:invoiceemail                                           Send invoice emails.
 session
  session:table                                               Create a migration for the session database table
 storage
  storage:link                                                Create the symbolic links configured for the application
 stub
  stub:publish                                                Publish all stubs that are available for customization
 synchronize
  synchronize:ad-am-roles                                     Synchronize ad am roles via nova api.
  synchronize:adp_api_hr_workers_data                         Synchronize adp api hr workers data.
  synchronize:asana_run                                       Synchronize asana_run
  synchronize:clients                                         Synchronize Clients via nova api.
  synchronize:dashboardclientsreport                          Synchronize Dashboard clients via nova api.
  synchronize:dashboards                                      Synchronize dashboards via nova api.
  synchronize:employee_client_stats                           Synchronize employee_client_stats
  synchronize:employee_stats                                  Synchronize employee_stats
  synchronize:fifteenfive                                     Synchronize fifteenfive
  synchronize:gd_report                                       synchronize gd_report
  synchronize:google_run13                                    Synchronize google 13.
  synchronize:google_run6                                     Synchronize google 6.
  synchronize:google_run_variable_ad_spend_tracker            Synchronize synchronize:google_run_variable_ad_spend_tracker.
  synchronize:google_web_dev_billing_synchronize              Synchronize google deb dev billing synchronize
  synchronize:industry                                        SynchronizeIndustry via nova api.
  synchronize:industry_clients                                Synchronize Industry Clients via nova api.
  synchronize:pad_employees                                   Synchronize pad_employees google doc
  synchronize:reportblueprints                                Synchronize ReportBlueprints via nova api.
  synchronize:reportstaffing                                  Synchronize ReportStaffing via nova api.
  synchronize:reportunderpacing                               Synchronize ReportUnderpacing via nova api.
  synchronize:salesforce_run                                  Synchronize salesforce run
  synchronize:salesforce_run3                                 Synchronize salesforce run3
  synchronize:salesforce_run4                                 Synchronize salesforce run4
  synchronize:salesforce_run5                                 Synchronize salesforce run5
  synchronize:salesforce_run6                                 Synchronize salesforce run6
  synchronize:strategist                                      Synchronize strategist via nova api.
  synchronize:synchronizeemployeeleadreport                   Synchronize Synchronize Employee Lead Report
  synchronize:user_titles                                     Synchronize ADP titles via nova api.
 ui
  ui:auth                                                     Scaffold basic login and registration views and routes
  ui:controllers                                              Scaffold the authentication controllers
 vendor
  vendor:publish                                              Publish any publishable assets from vendor packages
 view
  view:cache                                                  Compile all of the application's Blade templates
  view:clear                                                  Clear all compiled view files
```

I'm using the latest version of laravel 10 and PHP 8.1.

I'm seeking any solutions that anyone may have. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you do `php artisan`? What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I added the php artisan output to the original post @aynber. let me know what you think

Comment: Try running `composer install` again. If you've run it with `--no-dev`, it won't install the testing suite.

Comment: I deleted the composer.lock, vendor folder, and reran composer install but it gives the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the following package `nunomaduro/collision`

Try running `composer require nunomaduro/collision` to resolve the issue.

It worked for me

Comment: This package is not responsible for the artisan test command.

Comment: it was the solution in my case and several others, as an outside dependency

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution [here:](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/php-artisan-command-test-is-not-defined)

If you do `composer install -o --no-dev`, you will not be able to run `php artisan test`

*I will never say I tried to run "php artisan test" on production*

Comment: Or you could have just looked at the comments on the question, where this was mentioned 3 months previous